# Cumulative vs. total vs. summed

Tags: differences

Consider a set of items, each having a certain cost. I would like to refer to the sum of the costs of the items in the set. Is there a difference between or a preference for one of the following options?

- Cumulative cost
- Total cost
- Summed cost

Comment: I would say "cumulative cost" primarily when the sum is over time ... "Summed cost" I have not heard, but I imagine you sum over various categories, all  occurring at the same time.

Comment: You can investigate (or at least begin to) the way these premodifiers are used by looking in dictionaries; in this case, example sentences may be the best way to distinguish slight differences. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cumulative+cost%2Ctotal+cost%2Csummed+cost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccumulative%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctotal%20cost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csummed%20cost%3B%2Cc0) for each two-word term will show relative frequency of compounding/collocating, often (not always) a good indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have items A, B, C costing 20, 30, 40 respectively.

The *total cost* or equivalently, the *cost of the items*, is 90. That is, 20 + 30 + 40.

The *progressive cost* is the series 20, 50, 90. That is, [20, 20+30, 20+30+40].

*Summed cost* is more problematic because the context can change what is summed.

Answer (score 1):

As I see it,
Total is the final figure. 
Cumulative is the progressive totalling of several figures. 
A. Summed figure is the figure arising of addition of several subtotals.